# What will be the Postgres equivalent for following SQL Server expression (X.column1 & PAG.column2 = PAG.column2 OR PAG.column2 = 0)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, plpgsql, amazon-rds

**NOTE**: I think the issue is with differences in *logical operator* **precedence**.

My Postgres solution is **(X.column1 AND (PAG.column2 = PAG.column2) OR PAG.column2= 0)**. But this is **wrong**, I know. It's not working.

Please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the same expression should work.  Perhaps Postgres has different rules for precedence of bitwise operations (although that would surprise me).  You can be explicit with:

```
select ( (X.column1 & PAG.column2) = PAG.column2 OR (PAG.column2 = 0) )
```